# An issue with a legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am asking you because I have a problem with a legend in ggplot2.
Here's a simplified case

```
library(ggplot2)
library(datasets)

bp <- ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group, color=group)) + geom_boxplot()

bp +scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9"), 
                      name="Experimental\nCondition",
                      breaks=c("ctrl", "trt1", "trt2"),
                      labels=c("legend 1", "legend 2", "legend 3"))  +
    scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "red", "green"), 
                   name="Experimental\nCondition",
                   breaks=c("ctrl", "trt1", "trt2"),
                   labels=c("legend 1", "legend 2", "legend 3"))
```

In this case my legend labels are : "legend 1", "legend 2" and "legend 3"

Now, I would like to have the same labels for my legend : "legend 1" (with still three legend boxes).
So my code is :

```
bp <- ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group, color=group)) + geom_boxplot()

bp +scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9"), 
                      name="Experimental\nCondition",
                      breaks=c("ctrl", "trt1", "trt2"),
                      labels=c("legend 1", "legend 1", "legend 1"))  +
    scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "red", "green"), 
                   name="Experimental\nCondition",
                   breaks=c("ctrl", "trt1", "trt2"),
                   labels=c("legend 1", "legend 1", "legend 1"))
```

But, clearly this is not what I want because from now on, I have 9 legend boxes.
Therefore my question is : how in such a case, can I have a legend with three boxes (each one for each boxplot) but with labels for the legend which could be the same ?
Besides, why ggplot2 treats my code like this ?

You would help me a lot, if you could help me !
Thanks for your help.
Excuse me for my english mistakes, actually I am a non-native.

Comment: Since your labels aren't unique, it doesn't know which fill and colour should get what label.. I suppose. So, it gives you all combinations. It doesn't, in any case, make sense to have a legend when all labels are identical, does it?

Comment: Setting aside Arun questions (which I have as well) you could try setting `guide = "none"` in `scale_color_manual`, although then the legend won't apply those outline colors to the legend symbols at all.

Comment: First thanks for your answers.
Arun, yes it does. But actually my problem is more complex than that. In fact I have to show legends with only some of the labels identical; and the problem is still the same.

Comment: juran, thanks for the advice but I want to keep colors of the boxplots on the label.
Yes, on this case I showed you, it is not embarrassing. But my real case treats lines with points, which have different colors and shapes, in order to distinguish them.

Comment: Mael, could you explain a bit more clearly what kind of legend you are looking for? Or maybe create a mock-up legend with any drawing software? Currently, I am neither sure if you just want 'legend 1' to be the guide's title instead of "Experimental Condition", nor is it clear to me, how many guides with how many boxes each you want to have. How many combinations of fill and outline colours are you looking for and what do these colours mean? Because as juran was pointing out, different labels for the same colour combination would be a very confusing graph... So, any clarification might help!

Comment: thunk, I want the legend shown in the Brian Diggs'answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises, I think, from how ggplot combines legends together. If they have the same title and labels, they can be combined. I'm guessing that there is a merge involved which, when given duplicate labels, effectively creates an outer join (all possible mixes of the combinations). I'm not sure if there is a right way to fix this, but here is a hack that works:

```
bp <- ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group, color=group)) + geom_boxplot()
bp +scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9"), 
                      name="Experimental\nCondition",
                      breaks=c("ctrl", "trt1", "trt2"),
                      labels=c("legend 1", "legend 1 ", "legend 1  "))  +
    scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "red", "green"), 
                   name="Experimental\nCondition",
                   breaks=c("ctrl", "trt1", "trt2"),
                   labels=c("legend 1", "legend 1 ", "legend 1  "))
```

So you have labels which are not the same, but which look the same.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Brian Diggs, and for your trick.
So there is no way to avoid this behavior.

Comment: I don't know of a way to avoid the behavior. I imagine that there was an implicit assumption that the labels were unique (because if they were not unique, why would they need different aesthetics) and so this may not be something that can be directly avoided.